# Access Denied page during login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I was able to login using spring security in  my spring boot application.Then I entered incorrect credentials and access denied page worked as expected.After that I tried to login with correct credentials,but access denied page is loading always.Can someone explain the solution?

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/showReg", "/", "/index.html", "/registerUser", "/login", "/showLogin", "/login/*")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/showLogin")
                .deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
                .and()
                .rememberMe();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**SecutityServiceImpl.java**

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public boolean login(String userName, String password) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token=new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userDetails,password,userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        boolean result = token.isAuthenticated();
        if (result){
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>` in your `web.xml` file

Comment: I have no web.xml file in my spring boot project

Comment: Any specific reason why you are having a custom implementation of the SecurityService? Logging in should actually work, even after deleting that class, as long as you have a UserDetailsService defined.

Comment: i added the following line 'requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache())' to configure method in websecutiyconfig.java and now my problem is sorted out.Basically tried to remove the cache.Is it a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to find out why access denied page,
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken with 3 argument constructor always sets authentication flag to true.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token=new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails,password,userDetails.getAuthorities());
```

so checking if authenticated result will be true which is not real authentication based status as you rely on in `if(result){...}`:

```
boolean result = token.isAuthenticated();<- always true
```

as for attempt to authenticate `authenticationManager.authenticate(token);` token here should represent authentication object constructed by user credentials like following:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token=new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(enteredUserName,enteredPassword);
```

which is passed to authentication manager which in turn delegates to registered authentication providers for authentication.
I think your SecurityServiceImpl mimicking authentication provider logic. I would suggest bring that logic to AuthenticationProvider implementation and register it with AuthenticationManagerBuilder.
Basic example:

```
@Component
public class AuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String enteredUserName = authentication.getName();
    String enteredPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    UserDetails ud = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

    // compare/check password

    // if password valid
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(ud,null,authorities);
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
}
```

}